# vue2 reactive effect in element-ui

Tags: vuejs2, reactive, element-ui

I'm currently using el-table of element-ui for data demo.
One of attr of el-table is :data, which you can bind the data of array you want.

Here comes the question, if I have multiple new object data of array to add in (or say push),
I known I need to use this.set(target, index, value) this method for reactive.

For exampple,
const datas = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
and new data is [{c: 3}, {d: 4}]
I'm not sure how to make use of this.$set.
I guess I have to destruct the new data.

Btw, I don't want adopt workaround like using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loop is not a workaround in this case. It is a necessity.

It would look like this:

```js
this.tableData.forEach((o, i) => {
  this.$set(this.tableData[i], 'key', 'value')
})
```

If you really don't want to use a loop then you can do it with recursive method like this:

```js
addRecursive(i = 0) {
  this.$set(this.tableData[i], 'key', 'value')
  i++
  if (i <= this.tableData.length - 1) this.addRecursive(i)
}
```

And these are simple examples when adding just one key/value pair.
If you have array then you need to loop and set it.

Full example of that is here https://codepen.io/jakob_/pen/LYdzYdj